# Making a circular motion selection menu

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-transitions, css-animations

I set out with the idea of making a menu with a neat animation for selecting languages that resembles howl's moving castle magic location selector :
[image]

the idea is that you have your choices arranged in a circle and when you select one the whole circle rotates to have your choice align at the top, the code pen I brainstormed on will give you an idea :
https://codepen.io/tatsujb/pen/EOVMjg

(the `(click)`s are because I work under angular)

but as I made this I started to realize I was going down the wrong path with rotating the dom because my flags would end up upside-down...

how can I make such a menu?

(yes in the end js will handle the css classes that I add : one css class for each possible rotation position, this way switching backwards, forwards and skipping steps will be possible).

I only need a baseline for a setup that wouldn't rotate the content of the multiple choices, I'll work out the js.

UPDATE :

I think I'm going to do something more like this :
https://codepen.io/tatsujb/pen/bQEEow

the problem with this solution is it doesn't have circular motion.

2nd UPDATE :

misorude 's suggestion to just rotate the innards seems to works okay :

https://codepen.io/tatsujb/pen/aQdZOm

Comment: _“because my flags would end up upside-down”_ - so, rotate them by an equal amount in the opposite direction …?

Comment: well that has two downfalls, one it's incredibly clumsy and unoptimized and two the level of complexity for how much rotation each circle would require to course-correct at each rotation level would make the code-complexity needed to accomplish something this rudimentary absurd, ...no?

Comment: _“the level of complexity for how much rotation each circle would require”_ - if you have four flags positioned in this the right side up to begin with, and then rotate the whole circle 90 degree clockwise - then each of the flags needs to be rotated by that same amount of 90 degrees counter-clockwise, for all of them to be pointing right side up again. That isn’t “complexity”, that is one single math operation, 360 minus x, or even more simple, a switch of the _sign_.

Comment: If you don’t want that, then you have to keep those elements out of the rotation to begin with (like only rotate the circle image in the background, have the flags positioned on top of that), and calculate where there new un-rotated position for each element needs to be afterwards. (And if you wanted them to move with the circle while its moving, you would also have to calculate a proper circular motion path between old and new position.)

Comment: what about doing it like this : https://codepen.io/tatsujb/pen/bQEEow ?

Comment: you know what all things considered it runs smoothly and doesn't seem to glitch : https://codepen.io/tatsujb/pen/aQdZOm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found @misorude's suggestion to work well enough for my purposes.

here's a codepen example : https://codepen.io/tatsujb/pen/aQdZOm

```
.select-es{
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    .choice{
      transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }
  }
```